# strtok_r save state behaviour

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok, strsep

The [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15961253) way to use `strtok_r` is as follows:

```
char* str = strdup(string);
char* save;
char* ptr = strtok_r(str, delim, &save);
while(ptr) {
  puts(ptr);
  ptr = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save);
}
```

When trying to inspect what actually is stored in `save`, I found it is just the rest of the unparsed string. So I tried to make the second call look like the first and wrote a wrapper as follows.

```
char* as_tokens(char** str, const char* const delim) {
  return strtok_r(NULL, delim, str);
}
```

This can be used like below which is much less verbose. We don't have to differentiate between first call and rest.

```
char* str = strdup(string);
char* ptr;
while(ptr = as_tokens(&str, delim))
  puts(ptr);
```

Are there any downsides in this approach? Am I causing any undefined behavior? I tried some edge cases and both approaches work similarly.

Online Compiler: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rkGiwXOUtzqrbMpP

P.S. Ignoring memory leaks for brevity.

---

**Update**

There already exists a function almost similar to my `as_tokens`: [strsep](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep).
It differs in the case when there are consecutive delimiters. `strsep` returns an empty string while `as_tokens` (i.e strtok_r) treats them as one.

Comment: I believe the way the state is saved is not specified in the `strtok_r` documentation, so relying on it would be risky.

Comment: Note, too, that *no* part of the string is stored in `save`.  `save` is a pointer.  However, it would not be at all surprising for `save` to *point to* the tail of the string.  It is important to maintain and be mindful of the distinction between a pointer and the thing to which it points.

Comment: The designers could have specified the implementation to work the way you want but chose not to.  You are violating the requirement that `saveptr` be unmodified from the previous call when `str` is NULL.

Comment: @stark Where exactly am I modifying saveptr from the previous call?

Comment: Wherever you set its value.

Comment: The requirement violated is actually *"On the first call to strtok_r(), str should point to the string to be parsed"*, but I guess the question here is exactly "Can it be violated?" I think the general answer would be "No", as nothing is allowing it.

Comment: Theoretically, an implementation could index the entire string during the first call (when `str` is not `NULL`), and `save` would point to the indexing data rather than just the tail of the string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, he makes every call a subsequent call, not a first call.

Comment: Right you are, @Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think creating an index would be possible as there is no way to free it.

Comment: @balki Isn't that true in general for whatever `save` points to? I don't see anything in the spec that says it must share memory with the original string, although that's the common implementation.

Comment: It's easier and safer to write your own implementation of `strtok_r` that will 100% behave this way then to depend on uncertain data.

Comment: @KamilCuk Or simply copy the code from glibc, since it's open source.

Comment: Also see the BSD [strsep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any downsides in this approach?

Yes, it loses the original value of `str`, making it impossible (in this case) to free it.  You therefore have a memory leak.  That could be solved by keeping a separate copy of the pointer, but that boils down to very nearly the same thing as your first code.

Additionally, as was observed in comments, it does not comply with the specifications of `strtok_r` in that the behavior of a call to `strtok_r` with the first argument `NULL` is defined only in the context of a previous call to `strtok_r` that provided the value to which the third argument points.

Also, it departs from idiomatic, well-understood use of `strtok_r`, even going so far as to hide it in a different function.  The normal idiom is not onerous, and it is well known and understood.  Being clever about it makes your code a bit harder to maintain.

> Am I causing any undefined behavior?

Yes, in the sense of "behavior that is not defined", as opposed to behavior that is explicitly called out as *un*defined.  But the relevant standards attribute the same significance to those alternatives.  See above.