# strtok_r throwing in random new lines

Tags: c, strtok

Hi everyone I've got a problem with `strtok_r` throwing in random new lines, and was wondering if anyone could show me why it would be doing that? From my understanding, it is printing a new line when the input has a new line at the end, but this doesn't happen every time and I'm not sure why. My motivation is to have an input string of multiple words, and for `strtok_r` to store the words individually into an array (storage).

```
char delimit[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";
char *tempword; //temporary word until it is stored into the temp array
for (int r = 0; r < line_count; r++) {
    int counting = 0; //location of where tempword is stored in temp[counting]
    tempword = strtok_r(ptrarray[r], delimit, &ptrarray[r]);
    while (tempword != NULL && strcmp(tempword,"\n") != 0 && strcmp(tempword, "\0") != 0) {
        printf("temp: %s\n", tempword);
        storage[r][counting] = strdup(tempword); 
        tempword = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptrarray[r]);
        counting++;   
    }
    storage[r][word_count] = NULL; //last argument = NULL for execvp function
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `ptrarray[r]` ***twice*** in your call to `strtok_r()`?  Have you looked at any [examples of how to use `strtok_r()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961253/c-correct-usage-of-strtok-r)?

Comment: On your first call to `strtok_r()`, you pass a delimiter string that includes several whitespace characters, including the newline.  The token, if any, parsed by that call will not contain a newline.  On the other hand, the calls inside the loop all pass a delimiter string containing only a space character.  This is valid, but not necessarily what you actually want.  Other than that, we probably need to see a [mre] to determine what's going on.

Comment: Note also that although it is not technically wrong to have `strtok_r()` re-use `ptrarray[r]` for forwarding state between calls, it is fishy, and it might cause issues elsewhere.  You can surely spare the space for a single independent pointer to be used for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much John, I'll try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to `strtok_r` should be the address of a `char *` to store the internal state for the next call to `strtok_r` with a `NULL` initial pointer to return the next token. You pass the address of the string pointer you are trying to parse, this is incorrect. You should instead pass the address of a separate variable.

Furthermore `strtok_r` will not return a pointer to the newline nor a pointer to an empty string, so the extra tests are redundant.

Finally, you should pass the same string of delimiters for all tokens.

Here is a modified version:

```
char delimiters[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";
for (int r = 0; r < line_count; r++) {
    char *tempword; //temporary word until it is stored into the temp array
    char *state;
    int counting = 0; //location of where tempword is stored in temp[counting]
    tempword = strtok_r(ptrarray[r], delimiters, &state);
    while (tempword != NULL) {
        printf("temp: %s\n", tempword);
        storage[r][counting] = strdup(tempword); 
        tempword = strtok_r(NULL, delimiters, &state);
        counting++;   
    }
    storage[r][word_count] = NULL; //last argument = NULL for execvp function
}
```