# Reading ID and Name from file separately

Tags: c, file, split

Just a quick question, I'm reading from a file in C and just want to split the ID from the Name of the book, it'd be great if you could use simpler functions as this is for a assignment and don't want to use stuff I haven't learnt.

Layout of file:

```
1001 Harry Potter\n
1002 Lord of the Flies\n
1003 To Kill a Mockingbird\n
```

and so on, sorry if I didn't explain well enough

Comment: [Use `strtok_r` to _tokenize_ text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961253/c-correct-usage-of-strtok-r) along defined boundaries (such as your `\n` characters). Avoid `strtok` because it's an ancient function that was designed in the days before reentrancy was considered important or useful.

Comment: @Dai: `strtok_r` is not part of ISO C, so OP may not be able to use it.

Comment: Have you learnt [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)?

Comment: Since `scanf()` is anything but simple, it presumably isn't an option for this exercise?  It _can_ do the job, but the requisite format is not obvious.  Is the ID to be treated as a number or a string?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel fgets is the only one out of those three, also have used scanf but after all my googling it doesn't look pretty haha

Comment: @Xavier.code: What about [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)? Have you learnt that function?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel no but I just looked through and we can use some stuff we haven't been taught so I'd be happy to use it if its gonna be a lot easier

Comment: @Xavier.code: You still have not answered the question by someone else whether the ID is supposed to be treated as a number or a string. Do you need to convert the ID to an `int`? Or do you only have to split the strings?

Comment: yes sorry, I want the ID to be an int and the name to be a string

Comment: I suggest that you call `fgets` in a loop, in order to read one line per loop iteration. In every loop iteration, you can call `strtol` to convert the ID to a `long int`. If you pass the address of a pointer variable (have you learnt pointers yet?) as a second parameter to `strtol`, then the function will return a pointer to the first character that was not part of the number, which should be the space character. You can then assume that all remaining characters up to the newline character are part of the name.

Comment: yeah I have learnt pointers, as all the numbers will be 4 digits long, am I able to use that in the strtol function?

Comment: @Xavier.code: The function `strtol` will not care how long the digits are, it will continue reading digits until it encounters the space character.

Comment: @Xavier.code: If you have trouble with your attempt, please [edit] your question and show the code of your attempt, and describe what problems you encountered.